# Vertical align bottom fails in Firefox & Opera

Tags: css

I have a menu where it has a height of 69px and want the text at the bottom the height within its space.

The link is JSFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/YFuFV/

```
<div class="header fondo_amarillo">

<div class="header_central">
    <div class="grid_12">
        <div class="menu_option"><a href="#">Option 5</a></div>
        <div class="menu_option"><a href="#">Option 5</a></div>
        <div class="menu_option"><a href="#">Option 4</a></div>
        <div class="menu_option"><a href="#">Option 3</a></div>
        <div class="menu_option"><a href="#">Option 2</a></div>
        <div class="menu_option"><a href="#">Option 1</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .header {
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
}
.header_central {
    max-width:960px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.menu_option a {
    font-family:'NeoSans-Light';
    font-size:18px;
    height:69px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    color:rgb(150,150,150);
    float:right;
    padding:0 5px;
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-align: end;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    display: box;
    box-align: end;
    box-pack: center;
}
.menu_option a:hover {
    color:rgb(84,84,84);
}
.fondo_amarillo {
    background-color:#FFFF58;
}
```

If you see this code in Chrome and Safari, it works as desired but not in Firefox. What hook should i use for amending this issue?

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bunch of things that is missing in your code, first of all you are using `display:box` ( now the right name will be `flexbox`), and like you probably already know this feature its not yet support for every browser then you need many prefix to make it work like it should. Another problem is that you are using float right in the element with `display:box` and that is causing a bug on firefox, but don't be worry everything have a solution and your is right **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/YFuFV/4/)**

**New CSS**

```
.menu_option{
    float: right;
}
.menu_option a {
    font-family:'NeoSans-Light';
    font-size:18px;
    height:69px;
    color:rgb(150,150,150);
    padding:0 5px;

    display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD: Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers.  */
    display: -moz-box;      /* OLD: Firefox (buggy) */ 
    display: -ms-flexbox;   /* MID: IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;  /* NEW, Chrome 21+ */
    display: flex;          /* NEW: Opera 12.1, Firefox 22+ */

   -webkit-box-align: end; -moz-box-align: end; /* OLD… */
   -ms-flex-align: end; /* You know the drill now… */
   -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
   align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Here is a very good tutorial from David Storey on Smashing Code, take a **[look](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/)**